# HttpURLConnection get uploaded path of server in android

Tags: android

I am uploading a file to a server. Now I want to check whether the file is uploaded or not. So I want to get the path of the uploaded file on the server. Can anybody tell me how to do this?. If I get the path I will check in the browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on where the server is storing that file.I don't think you can get the path from your application.You have to check the folder where server is saving the data.